# Oracle LDAP Move User to a Different OU with Java

Tags: java, oracle, ldap

I'm looking for a way to change the OU of a user in my Oracle LDAP, using Java. So far I found only the ***DirContext.rename*** method, but that results in a corrupted LDAP entry. Below is the code I tried.

```
    Hashtable<String, String> environment = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    environment.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    environment.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");
    environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:10389");
    environment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "uid=admin,ou=system");
    environment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "admin");

    DirContext ctx = null;
    try {
        ctx = new InitialDirContext(environment);
        String oldCn = "uid=wso21,ou=wso2,ou=Users,dc=WSO2,dc=ORG";
        String newCn = "uid=wso21,ou=vodafone,ou=Users,dc=WSO2,dc=ORG";
        ctx.rename(oldCn, newCn);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            ctx.close();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

After this is executed, the moved entry is there but no attributes are present.

TIA!

Comment: export the old entry to an ldif file, then create the new one by changing the DN, and finnaly delete the old entry

Comment: That's what I did for the moment! But was wondering whether we have something more straightforward. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please modify try Block:

```
try {
    ctx = new InitialDirContext(environment);
    String oldDn = "uid=wso21,ou=wso2,ou=Users,dc=WSO2,dc=ORG";
    String newDn = "uid=wso21,ou=vodafone,ou=Users,dc=WSO2,dc=ORG";
    String newCn="newCN";
    String newSn="newSN";
    Attributes attrs = ctx.getAttributes(oldDn);
    ctx.rename(oldDn,newDn);
    attrs.remove("cn");
    attrs.remove("sn");
    //if needed remove more attributes
    attrs.put("cn",newCn);
    attrs.put("sn",newSn);
    //if needed add more attributes
    ctx.modifyAttributes(newDn, DirContext.ADD_ATTRIBUTE, attrs);
}
```

Comment: If you have got any operational attribute to copy, you should apply 
`
String [] opAttrNames;  //and //
Attributes opattrs = ctx.getAttributes(oldDn, opAttrNames);
'